# Python regex with re.findall

Tags: python, regex

I work with Python 2.7. It is my first question here.

Here is my code:

```
import re
string = "0581111105822222749533333"
result = re.findall(r'058',string) # ['058', '058']
```

I want to add 5 digits after `058` and receive:

```
# ['05811111','05822222']
```

How to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: format your code as code. The way you did this doesn't make clear what you need to do.

Comment: not getting better. Vote to close as unclear :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract what you need using `058\d{5}` pattern. This matches '058' characters and keeps extracting 5 digits after those.